# Function in another function's parameters (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I've been studying a new code about a distint function call in JavaScript. 
Here it is:

```
function createCode(tree, path, code){
   if(!tree) throw new Expception("Invalid tree");
   if(!tree.left && !tree.right){
      code[tree.letters[0]] = path;
        return code;
   }
   createCode(tree.left,"0"+path,code);
   createCode(tree.right,"1"+path,code);
   return code;
}
```

What I don't understand are the next parameters, when the function is called:

```
print('loaded');
var forrest = test1();
var code = createCode(forrest,"",{});
```

When I compile the code, I try to print(code); and it displays [Object object].
I don't know what is the function createCode() returning.

What kind of access do I have to 'code'?

Comment: You question is not clear, what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) like `print(JSON.stringify(code))`

Comment: @Madhu what I need is to check the state of what createCode() is returning.

Comment: @Grundy thanks. This is what I was looking for:
`{"a":"0","i":"01","u":"0011","o":"1011","e":"111"}`

Comment: @artavia23 so you problem solved and question is answered? :-)